# How to click a button inside a pop-up in selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking to click on a button that appear when you have no cookies from this website, named "accéder au site".
Here is the process to have this button :

1. No cookies
2. Go to https://www.allocine.fr
3. Click the "Accepter et accéder gratuitement" button
4. Then a pop-up for promoting a movie appear with a "accéder au site" button in order to skip it. (the pop-up last for about 5/10s)

I'm using Selenium (Python).

This is the website : https://www.allocine.fr
I tried many things such as css selector, partial link text, switching to frame but nothing is working.
I also thought that my problem was that I have to wait before the button appears, but this isn't working too.

Here is my code :

```
from yggtorrentscraper import YggTorrentScraperSelenium
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

PATH_CHROME_DRIVER = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH_CHROME_DRIVER, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.allocine.fr")

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/span/div/button[2]'))).click()

#not working
#WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/a'))).click()
```

Here is also the HTML of the button

```
<div id="dfp_interstitial">
<div id="dfp_interstitial__top">
    <div id="dfp_interstitial__top-logo" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PBjnn15gFS4/XJzvx16iKdI/AAAAAAAADro/yVpahUmuWwMxthTXopnE0lLgJ0zJxG0qgCK8BGAs/s0/2019-03-28.png&quot;);"></div>
    <div id="dfp_interstitial__top-close">
        accéder au site &nbsp;<span class="dfp_interstitial__arrow-right"></span><span class="dfp_interstitial__arrow-right"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="dfp_interstitial__click" target="_blank">
    <img id="dfp_interstitial__image" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/simgad/5287997328350019355?" style="max-width: 1280px;">
</a>
```

I have really no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things :

1. `CSS` is preferred over `xpath`. Note that you are using absolute xpath, which is brittle in nature.
2. Use explicit waits.
3. **accéder au site** is in an iframe, so you'd have to switch to iframe first then you can click on this button.

**code :-**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.allocine.fr/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[onclick^='Didomi.setUserAgreeToAll']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id^='google_ads_iframe_'][id$='homepage/home_2']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "dfp_interstitial__top-close"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This is so clear and understandable, thanks a lot !!
I also have one more question, I want to click on that "Rechercher" button.
I used "driver.switch_to.default_content()" to get back to the original iframe, and "wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title^=Rechercher]"))).click()", which works great except in headless mode (TimeoutException), do you know why ?

Comment: @UnlockeerFromFrance : headless is not that stable as GUI mode is. I would recommend to use it in full screen mode, also put hardcoded sleep if it's necessary.

Comment: I got it working with your advice, I added a 1920x1080 resolution "options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")" and it works great. Thank you, I will keep in mind that GUI mode is more stable than headless!